# Facing issue while Configuring MDB and MQ in jboss 7.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, ibm-mq, ejb-3.0, jboss-mdb

I was using jboss 6.4 before now i am migrating to jboss 7.1 and MQ 8,  We have used jboss-ejb3.xml to configure MDBs and MQs, But after migrating to jboss 7.1 i am getting following error can some one please help me to resolve this problem

```
2019-02-11 12:13:03,739 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] AMQ151004: Instantiating null "TRANS.CMUPT.REQ.MCOF" directly since UseJNDI=false.
2019-02-11 12:13:05,614 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar: MQJCA4004:Message delivery to an MDB 'null' failed with exception: 'Could not initialize class com.ge.trans.mcs.msgejb.ejb.imr.mdb.InBoundMessageMDB$$$endpoint4'.
2019-02-11 12:13:05,762 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] AMQ151004: Instantiating null "TRANS.CMUPT.REQ.MCOF" directly since UseJNDI=false.
2019-02-11 12:13:07,785 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] AMQ151004: Instantiating null "TRANS.CMUPT.REQ.MCOF" directly since UseJNDI=false.
2019-02-11 12:13:09,815 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] AMQ151004: Instantiating null "TRANS.CMUPT.REQ.MCOF" directly since UseJNDI=false.
2019-02-11 12:13:11,836 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] AMQ151004: Instantiating null "TRANS.CMUPT.REQ.MCOF" directly since UseJNDI=false.
2019-02-11 12:13:13,854 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] AMQ151004: Instantiating null "TRANS.CMUPT.REQ.MCOF" directly since UseJNDI=false.
2019-02-11 12:13:15,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar: MQJCA4004:Message delivery to an MDB 'null' failed with exception: 'Could n
```

New logs

Seeing flowing issue

```
2019-02-12 12:37:17,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar:                                : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:338)
2019-02-12 12:37:17,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar:                                : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312)
2019-02-12 12:37:17,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar:                                : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1227)
2019-02-12 12:37:17,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar:      Caused by [1] --> Message : com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2053' ('MQRC_Q_FULL').
2019-02-12 12:37:17,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar:                          Class : class com.ibm.mq.MQException
2019-02-12 12:37:17,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar:                          Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
2019-02-12 12:37:17,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar:                                : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQPoison.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQPoison.java:1423)
2019-02-12 12:37:17,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar:                                : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQPoison.put(WMQPoison.java:984)
2019-02-12 12:37:17,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar:                                : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQPoison.deadletter(WMQPoison.java:894)
```

This is the only error i am seeing now please help me to resolve this issue.

```
01:25:55,618 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (default-threads - 2) wmq.jmsra.rar: MQJCA4004:Message delivery to an MDB 'null' failed with exception: 'Could not initialize class com.ge.trans.mcs.msgejb.ejb.alerter.mdb.AlerterMDB$$$endpoint8'.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the rest of the last log entry, it appears to cut off at `failed with exception: 'Could n`.  Don't leave us hanging on the only line in your output that appears to actually reference IBM MQ.

Comment: Looks like some sort of classpath error with your MDB:
com.ge.trans.mcs.msgejb.ejb.imr.mdb.InBoundMessageMDB

The error states that it can't create the 'endpoint4' subclass.

Comment: When you edited the question notice how I formatted your errors for readability.  The simplest way is to place three backticks `\`\`\`` on a line above and below your errors, this formats all the text on the lines between as a fixed with font.

Comment: Do the answer help you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

`reason '2053' ('MQRC_Q_FULL')` just means what it sounds like, the destination queue you are putting to is full, this means that it has reached the `MAXDEPTH` number of messages.

`Could not initialize class com.ge.trans.mcs.msgejb.ejb.alerter.mdb.AlerterMDB$$$endpoint8`

In a comment from Tim McCormick he stated the following:

> Looks like some sort of classpath error with your MDB: com.ge.trans.mcs.msgejb.ejb.imr.mdb.InBoundMessageMDB The error states that it can't create the 'endpoint4' subclass.

Ensure the endpoint4 subclass is in your classpath.

Comment: Even after clearing Q i still have flowing issue                         ```2019-02-12 12:56:45,686 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar: MQJCA4004:Message delivery to an MDB 'null' failed with exception: 'Could not initialize class com.ge.trans.mcs.msgejb.ejb.omr.mdb.OutBoundMessageMDB$$$endpoint3'.
2019-02-12 12:56:45,687 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] wmq.jmsra.rar: MQJCA4004:Message delivery to an MDB 'null' failed with exception: 'Could not initialize class com.ge.trans.mcs.msgejb.ejb.autoretryer.mdb.AutoRetryerMDB$$$endpoint12'.

Comment: That is a different error, looks like what you first posted.  My answer was specifically related to the 2053.

Comment: You should always edit your question to post error logs, comments do not format things and makes it hard to read.  Earlier error looks like what Tim commented on about a classpath error.

Comment: ```
01:25:55,618 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (default-threads - 2) wmq.jmsra.rar: MQJCA4004:Message delivery to an MDB 'null' failed with exception: 'Could not initialize class com.ge.trans.mcs.msgejb.ejb.alerter.mdb.AlerterMDB$$$endpoint8'.```   
Sorry for not editing this the only error i am getting now.